# Visual Studio 2015 configuring a single C++ project for Android and Windows platforms

Tags: android, windows, visual-studio, static-libraries, visual-studio-2015

In Visual Studio Community 2015 I'm trying to create a static library that would be shared between Android and Windows platform projects. I've successfully created the library project for Android platform and I'm using it without any problem.

Howerver, I **can't** seem to find a way how to add a Windows platform support for my library project!

It looks like for my currently created android static library project (*called "Engine"*) a "`<New...>`" option is missing in the selection box!?

[image]

**EDIT**: I've created my library as a Visual **C++** - Cross Platform - Static library (**Android**) in a hope that I will be able to add the **C++** Windows x86 and x64 platform support later on. But now I'm struggling to find a way to do that.

[image]

Is there any way I can use a single project for Android and Windows platforms? (*Like i.e. using x86 and x64 for Windows...*)

Comment: Why kind of projects do you want to create? A portable class library targeting Any CPU is the option you should go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, looks like it's not possible to have a single C++ project configurable for multiple platforms (*like i.e. for android and windows platforms*)

After doing some research I've noticed that there is a nice way to **share** the same source code between multiple project in a bit similar ways as if using the static library!

This suits for me perfectly because I have some "common" things that I want my Android and Windows platform projects to share.

[image]

Then to i.e. you Windows or Android project properties menu.
Click "**Add**" -> "**Reference...**"
[image]

In the "**Add Reference**" window go to "**Shared Projects**" and select your desired "sharable" project.

That's it!